# Avoiding unnecessary computations within loops

Tags: programming

Consider the following data:

```
test = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {10, 5, 3, 3}];
```

How can I do the following without the `For` loops, e.g. using `Table` or similar *Mathematica* functions?

```
Module[{res = {}}, 
  For[i = 1, i < 11, i++,
    For[j = 1, j < 6, j++, 
      p = test[[i, j, 1]];
      q = test[[i, j, 2]];
      r = Cross[p,q];
      mat = Orthogonalize[{p, q, r}];
      For[k = 1, k < 6, k++,
        AppendTo[res, mat.SeparationVector[p, test[[i, k, 1]], 2]]]]];
  res]
```

where

```
SeparationVector[x_, y_, z_] := If[# < z/2, x - y, Sequence @@ {}]& @
  Sqrt[Total[((x - y) - z*Round[(x - y)/z])^2]]
```

My Problem with using `Table` is that between the `j` and `k` indices, I define variables that depend on `j` so that I don't have to calculate these values for every iteration of `k`. I don't know how to achieve the same functionality without the `For` loops. But this is *Mathematica*, and I know there are better and faster ways to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: You could nest the `Table`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one could do the following using `Table`

```
    Table[Table[Table[p = test[[i, j, 1]]; q = test[[i, j, 2]];
 r = Cross[p, q]; mat = Orthogonalize[{p, q, r}]; 
mat.SeparationVector[p, test[[i, k, 1]], 2], {k, 5}], {j, 5}], {i, 10}]
```